# What's faster in terms of timing closure, multiple "ifs" or an "if-else"?

Tags: if-statement, verilog, synthesis

Let's say I have some logic dependent on three signals `a`, `b`, and `c` to assign a variable `d`.

If I know `a` and `b` and `c` are logically (as in *I* know they will be, the tool won't necessarily be able to figure that out) going to be mutually exclusive, what would be faster in terms of the synthesized result?

This:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin

   if (a) begin
       d <= foo;
   end

   if (b) begin
       d <= bar;
   end

   if (c) begin
       d <= fizz;
   end

end
```

Or this:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin

   if (c) begin
       d <= fizz;
   end else if (b) begin
       d <= bar;
   end else if (a) begin
       d <= foo;
   end

end
```

I would think the former because there's less nesting, as in there's no check this, then check this, then check this. But I'd say the latter because if one conditional evaluates first, it doesn't need to consider the results of the other conditions. But maybe I'm mistaken and missing something.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: HDL compilers are very good at optimizing, definitely for a simple circuit like this. I think you will not find a difference.

Comment: you need to make sure that the synthesizer understands that they are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most synthesis tools would likely create the same logic for both based on how you have structured it with the first case being a->b->c and the second being c->b->a with regards to conditional checks.

With that said...

Whoever needs to look at this would potentially not know about the exclusivity of the logic, leading them to control it wrong potentially if those conditional checks are controlled through some external signals. It's also hard to read from the standpoint of needing to really examine the code. An if/else clearly distinguishes "if this, else do this" and there is no ambiguity with regards to the outcome. I had to look at the order of the if's in the first structure before I saw what you were doing and how it matched.

Since we are talking about speed of logic, we can also discuss simulator speed. On your first structure, you are now causing the simulator do 3 if checks. The 2nd could be as low as 1 and high as 3. While you wouldn't see this impact performance if you have a smaller sim, if this was some logic that is instantiated many times on a fast clock, it would start to eat up sim cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Both pieces of code will result in a priority mux. The only difference being, the order of the priority is decided by you/synthesis tool in the second/first pieces of code respectively.

However if you are targeting this code for an FPGA, you can embed the mutually exclusive part into the code with something like this

```
always@(*)
begin
    case ( {a,b,c} )
    3'b000: d_in <= d;
    3'b001: d_in <= foo;
    3'b010: d_in <= bar;
    3'b100: d_in <= fizz;
    endcase
end

always@(posedge clk)
begin
    d<=d_in;
end
```

Regards,
Bharadwaj